# 18.04.1 Server keeps creating /var/lib/dpkg/lock and /var/cache/apt/archives/lock. What now?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm working with a fresh install of 18.04.1 from which I have removed certain packages that communicate asynchronously with other hosts, having pinned them, along with certain other packages, for non-installation.  Every time I run (a) `dpkg -i`, (b) `apt-get install`, or (c) `aptitude install`, the lock files /var/lib/dpkg/lock and /var/cache/apt/archives/lock are re-created and I must remove them manually before I can run a, b, or c again.  This never happened before 18.04.1, nor on any issue of 16.04.  Q: What's broken, and how can I avoid the necessity of removing the lock files manually?

`dpkg --configure -a` does not help, and it does not remove the lock files.  If it finds something to do, it fixes it, creates /var/lib/dpkg/lock and just leaves that lock file there, while exiting normally.

`ps aux | grep -E 'apt|dkpg'` yields

```
    root     24494  0.0  0.0  14428  1064 pts/0    S+   11:48   0:00 grep --color=auto -E apt|dkpg
```

i.e., there are no hangover processes that might account for the problem.

As user535733 requested, here is a terminal session that demonstrates the phenomenon.  (By the way, I have now fresh-installed 2 hosts with 18.04.1 and they both show the same troubling behavior.)

```
~  root@sea{3}# date; ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
Tue Aug 14 08:52:46 EDT 2018
ls: cannot access '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Aug 11 04:48 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
~  root@sea{3}# ls -d /var/cache/apt/archives
/var/cache/apt/archives/
~  root@sea{3}# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
~  root@sea{3}# date; ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
Tue Aug 14 08:53:58 EDT 2018
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Aug 14 08:53 /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Aug 11 04:48 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
~  root@sea{3}# date; ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; 
Tue Aug 14 08:54:36 EDT 2018
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Aug 14 08:53 /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Aug 11 04:48 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
~  root@sea{3}# date; ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; 
Tue Aug 14 08:54:44 EDT 2018
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
~  root@sea{3}# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
~  root@sea{3}# date; ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; 
Tue Aug 14 08:55:09 EDT 2018
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Aug 14 08:54 /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Aug 14 08:54 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
~  root@sea{3}# date; ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; 
Tue Aug 14 08:56:20 EDT 2018
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
~  root@sea{3}# dpkg -r telnet
(Reading database ... 310184 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing telnet (0.17-41) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
~  root@sea{3}# date; ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; 
Tue Aug 14 08:56:53 EDT 2018
ls: cannot access '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Aug 14 08:56 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
rm: cannot remove '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
~  root@sea{3}# date; ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; 
Tue Aug 14 08:57:17 EDT 2018
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
~  root@sea{3}# dpkg -r telnet
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove telnet, only the config
 files of which are on the system; use --purge to remove them too
~  root@sea{3}# dpkg -i telnet
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'telnet': No such file or directory
~  root@sea{3}# apt-get -y install telnet
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  telnet
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 67.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 165 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 telnet amd64 0.17-41 [67.1 kB]
Fetched 67.1 kB in 0s (207 kB/s)
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Selecting previously unselected package telnet.
(Reading database ... 310185 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../telnet_0.17-41_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking telnet (0.17-41) ...
Setting up telnet (0.17-41) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/telnet.netkit to provide /usr/bin/telnet (telnet) in auto mode
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
~  root@sea{3}# date; ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; 
Tue Aug 14 08:58:21 EDT 2018
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Aug 14 08:57 /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Aug 14 08:58 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
~  root@sea{3}# date; ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; 
Tue Aug 14 08:58:24 EDT 2018
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
~  root@sea{3}# apt-get -y install telnet
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
telnet is already the newest version (0.17-41).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
~  root@sea{3}# date; ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; 
Tue Aug 14 08:59:25 EDT 2018
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Aug 14 08:59 /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Aug 14 08:59 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
~  root@sea{3}# date; ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; 
Tue Aug 14 08:59:43 EDT 2018
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
~  root@sea{3}#
```

I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that I have pinned the following packages for non-installation, just as I have done without problems in the past:

```
    apport-gtk
    apturl
    kerneloops-daemon
    landscape-common
    libfam0
    libreoffice-calc
    libreoffice-core
    libreoffice-gnome
    libreoffice-gtk
    libreoffice-style-elementary
    libreoffice-writer
    lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings
    light-locker
    lxd
    nagios-images
    nagios-plugins
    popularity-contest
    postgresql
    postgresql-9.5
    postgresql-9.6
    postgresql-client-9.5
    postgresql-client-9.6
    postgresql-contrib-9.5
    postgresql-contrib-9.6
    python3-distupgrade
    python3-distupgrade
    python3-update-manager
    python-pycurl
    samba-common
    samba-common-bin
    smbclient
    snap-confine
    snapd
    software-center
    software-center-aptdaemon-plugins
    squashfs-tools
    squashfs-tools
    ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
    ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
    ubuntu-server
    ubuntu-standard
    unattended-upgrades
    update-manager
    update-manager-core
    update-manager-gnome
    update-notifier
    update-notifier-common
    update-notifier-core
    virtualbox-guest-dkms
    virtualbox-guest-utils
    virtualbox-guest-x11
    whoopsie
```

Comment: I have pinned unattended-upgrades for non-installation, it is not installed, and the problem still exists.

Comment: Erm, just to eliminate what could be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): exactly what problems do you experience? Please add the relevant details to your question.

Comment: I'm asking because you mention that aptitude and dpkg "work just fine".

Comment: I will try to be clearer.  (1) I run one of: dpkg, aptitude, apt-get.  It works. (2) I run any one of them again, but it refuses because either /var/lib/dpkg/lock or /var/cache/apt/archives/lock exists.  (3) I remove the offending file(s).  (4) [start again at #1].

Comment: Please modify your question to include that information. Comments are for transient information. Run a `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to make sure that your  packages are in a consistent state. Next time the blockage happens, run `ps aux | grep -E 'apt|dkpg'` and include the output in your question.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete output of a dpkg (and apt) session(s) that failed to remove a lockfile.